# How to switch git repo in multi module IntelliJ projects window

Tags: intellij-idea

Just curious how to switch git repos in multi module intelliJ window. Here Module means completely separate git repos.

When I expand that git label I can see correct git branch in each corresponding module. I was expecting to change that whenever I click on different modules in the project explorer.

my IntelliJ version - `2021.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)`

[image]

Comment: Just realized that if open-up any of the module file, then it changes to corresponding git repo branch. Is that the ONLY way? Just clicking the module folder won't do that.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It's the only way to see in branch widget what branches is currently checked out in particular repository. Otherwise you will need to open a branch popup.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a thing such as switching git repos.

What you see in the bottom-right is the branch that belongs to the currently opened file in your editor. If you look at the branches dialog and scroll to the top, you can view the active branches for all the repos that are connected to your project. So yes, opening a file from a repo seems to be the only way to view the active branch of that repo in the bottom-right.

You can open the branch dialog via **Git > Branches**, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, or clicking on the active branch on the bottom-right.